# How to enable http/2 in sails.js

Tags: sails.js, http2

I have searched about how to enable http/2 for my sails.js app, but I haven't found anything.

I initially thought that it was already enabled, so I used the "HTTP/2 and SPDY indicator" plug-in for chrome, but when I visit my website it says "NOT SPDY-enabled".

I'm interested specifically about the multiplexing feature of http/2 (so I can use multiple js files instead of a big one).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like around the time you were looking for this, someone created a hook for it: [sails-hook-http2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-http2).